# JQuery Isotope ordering not ordering divs accurately

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

My url is leftsideart (dot) co (dot) nz

I am using the following isotope setup:

```
jQuery('#post-area').isotope({
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },
    getSortData : {
        number : function( $elem ) {
        return parseInt( $elem.find('.order').text(), 10 );
        }
    },
    sortBy : 'number',
    sortAscending : true,
    animationEngine : 'jquery'
});

var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#post-area');
jQuerycontainer.imagesLoaded( function() {
    jQuerycontainer.isotope();
});
```

but my divs are not ordering correctly. Isotope is definitely affecting the order as I have  tried echoing random numbers in my wordpress loop as opposed to incrementing numbers and the divs shuffle accordingly.

Also, just to be sure, when I change the change 'sortAscending' to false then the general order of the divs is reversed.

Does Isotope offer only a general ordering as opposed to an exact ordering?

Comment: Sorry just bumping this in the hope for an answer.

Comment: If each item being ordered has a fixed height then this fixes the issue so I am assuming that the isotope ordering is only exact under these conditions.

I am leaving this open just in case someone has a solution for items with varied heights.

Comment: Nice once @brad, that fixed the issue for me. Shame it can't handle varying heights, but we can't have it all i guess...

Comment: Still an issue it seems!

Answer (score 0):

for an similar kind of problem, this worked for me

```
layoutMode: 'cellsByColumn',
cellsByColumn: {
  columnWidth: 240,
  rowHeight: 360
}
```

docs are here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/layout-modes.html