# jQuery: Isotope Causing Incorrect Ordering

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

URL: http://iff.rocks/artists/

It is supposed to be ordered alphabetically (horizontally), which when you look at the source code, it is. When you inspect element in Chrome for an artist, there seems to be some odd styles injected for each `<article>`

Amongst some other styles, the one that is bugging me is the translate3d one. The numbers represent the order of the artists

1. translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
2. translate3d(411px, 0px, 0px);
3. translate3d(822px, 0px, 0px);
4. translate3d(822px, 0px, 0px);
5. translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
6. translate3d(411px, 0px, 0px);
7. translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
8. translate3d(822px, 0px, 0px);
9. translate3d(411px, 0px, 0px);

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137293/jquery-isotope-ordering-not-ordering-divs-accurately - seems to be the fixed height issue

Comment: You problem is not clearly stated. You say it is ordered as expected. What exactly is the issue your having with the translate3d styles?

Comment: It is supposed to be ordered alphabetically - which to be denotes that it isn't ordered alphabetically. Issue sorted now anyway with my reply.